# mingw32 linker error when including QDebug

Tags: windows, qt, linker, mingw

I have this minimal example:

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += qt console
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

```
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}
```

which gives this **link error** when building the project:

> c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid argument

The **link command** looks like this:

> g++ -Wl -Wl -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o debug\test.exe debug/main.o  -L"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.8.1\mingw\lib" -lQtCored4

**My setup:**

- Windows XP SP3
- Qt SDK version 1.2.1 (QtCreator 2.4.1, Qt Desktop version 4.8.1) (fresh install at `C:\QtSDK\`)
- MinGW32 version 4.4.0 (included in Qt SDK at `C:\QtSDK\mingw\`)

---

If I remove the `#include <QDebug>`, it compiles fine. If I include some other Qt header file, like for example QCoreApplication, it compiles fine, too.

**EDIT:** Here is a very strange minimal example. Consider an empty main function like above. Now if i put these includes, it fails to link:

```
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVariant>
```

But if I remove *one of them*, it links without an error.

What's the problem? Why doesn't mingw tell me *what the invalid argument is*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im wondering is the linker could not find the lQtCored4 lib? Is it actually in the -L directory?

Comment: It seems to be a problem of this type, but I'm wondering why the error only appears when including QDebug, not another Qt header. I just noticed that Qt SDK already includes MinGW 4.4. I think I messed up the toolchains in the settings. I currently completely de- and reinstall the whole Qt SDK and will report if the problem still exists. (I already spent 2 hours resolving this error, so I don't have any patience to find and correct wrong settings...)

Comment: After reinstalling Qt SDK, the problem still persists. Note that the pre- / absence of the `#include <QDebug>` doesn't change the command being executed when linking the application. I really can't explain what the error means, since the error message doesn't explain *what's wrong* with the arguments.

Comment: I added another minimal example which I really cannot explain (see the edit in the question).